# I didn't get notification for this comment on my inbox

Tags: bug, status-completed, area-51, global-inbox

I only had notification for [Jez's second comment on this question](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/29528/french-language-usage/29529#29529) in my inbox.

It's only when I visited Area51 for a while later today that I was alerted of a comment, with a message at the top (the same kind that you get when you win a new badge).

Sorry. That's really all I have,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of today, Area 51 comments are put into the global inbox. The behavior is identical to the rest of the SE network.