# notification for comments on Example Questions in Area51

Tags: bug, area-51, notifications

I'm not getting notifications for any comments on my Example Questions in Area51

Comment: Not only no notifications, but also no rep changes shown.

Comment: @MrLore indeed looks like a bug, considering [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80046/i-didnt-get-notification-for-this-comment-on-my-inbox)

Comment: Probably by design, as Area51 runs on a very much outdated fork of the Stack Exchange software stack and doesn't support notifications.

Comment: Related, possibly a dupe: [Area51 Reputation changes do not show up in the new Top Bar](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/211245)