# Area 51 reputation not shown in 'Your Communities' drop-down

Tags: bug, area-51, top-bar, communities-list

If you have Area 51 followed, the network drop-down does not display the reputation for the site:

[image: Hand drawn red circle]

Is this an error or a bug? As with the other quirks of Area 51 mentioned in [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/233634/notification-for-comments-on-example-questions-in-area51), it's hard to tell.

Answer (score 3):

As Nick explains in [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/211253/152859), 
Area 51 is running on the early SE 2.0 platform and doesn't support exporting its rep to the dropdown. Not a bug. [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign).

Comment: Will it ever show reputation?